# Position with Exception pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching

I have list `{1, 2, 3, <|"a" -> 1|>, 4, 2}`, and I would to find positions of all elements that match the case NOT INTEGER, namely `Except[_Integer]`, on {1} level.
So, my expression looks:

```
Position[{1, 2, 3, <|"a" -> 1|>, 4, 2}, Except[_Integer], {1}]
```

But it returns `{{0}, {4}}`

I'm surprised with position `{0}`. What is explanation for this, and how to avoid `{0}` in result?

Comment: Position matches all parts of an expression, including the head. You can get rid of it by specifying Heads->False.